React Application shows results in the wrong sort order
For some reason I can't figure out why the results are in the wrong sort order.
I think my State might be my problem.  It's not being set correctly or in the right place when different buttons are clicked that should provide the results in a different order.
Doing some searching but doesn't seem to help:

Accessing a dynamically created set of elements in react

react set state not rerendering component


Current Problem:

Application loads with Employees within Name Order

Clicking "Department Listing" shows Employees within Department Order

Clicking "Employees" shows Employees within Department Order but the Employees should be within Name Order

Once "Department Listing" is clicked, Employees remain within
Department Order even when "Employees" or "Reset" is clicked.

setSearchResults(cards) is being set in SearchText for the
"Employees" and "Reset" buttons but doesn't seem to take effect once
"Department Listing" is clicked.


Desired Functionality:

Application loads with Employees within Name Order
Clicking "Department Listing" shows Employees within Department Order
Clicking "Employees" or "Reset" shows Employees within Name Order

Cards - Should always contain the Employee Data sorted by Name Order
APP

import { useState } from 'react';
import { employees } from './search-data/data.js';
import SearchHeader from './search-header/page.js';
import SearchText from './search-text/page.js';
import SearchResults from './search-results/page.js';

function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(employees);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState(employees);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState("employees");

  
  return (
    
    <>
    
    <SearchHeader />
    <SearchText cards={cards} setIsLoading={setIsLoading} setSelection={setSelection} setSearchResults={setSearchResults} />
    <SearchResults setIsLoading={setIsLoading} isLoading={isLoading} selection={selection} searchResults={searchResults} />
    
    </>

  );

}

export default App;



SearchText

import { useState } from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import InputGroup from 'react-bootstrap/InputGroup';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { faMagnifyingGlass, faPeopleGroup, faBuildingUser, faArrowsRotate } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';

const SearchText = ({ cards, setIsLoading, setSelection, setSearchResults }) => {
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");

  const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

  }

  const onChange = (event) => {
    (event.target.value) || setSearchResults(cards);

    const fields = ['NAME', 'CAMPUS', 'DEPARTMENT', 'JOBTITLE'];
    const query = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filterData = (cards, fields, query) => {
      return cards.filter(record => fields.some(field => record[field]?.toLowerCase().includes(query)));
    
    };

    setIsLoading(true);
    setEnteredText(event.target.value);
    setSearchResults(filterData(cards, fields, query));
    setSelection("employees");

  }

  const onReset = (event) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setEnteredText("");
    setSearchResults(cards);
    setSelection("employees");

  }

  const onDepartment = (event) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setEnteredText("");
    setSearchResults(cards);
    setSelection("department listing");

  }


  return (
    
    <Form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
      <Container className="container-fluid p-3">
        <Form.Group as={Row} className={`mb-3 ${utilStyles.divPadding}`}>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <InputGroup className={utilStyles.searchBar}>
              <InputGroup.Text className={utilStyles.inputGroupText}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} className={utilStyles.icon} />
                <Form.Control id="SearchText" type="text" placeholder="Search Last Name; First Name; Campus; Deparment....." value={enteredText} onChange={onChange} className={`${utilStyles.inputField} ${utilStyles.inputPadding}`} />
              </InputGroup.Text>
            </InputGroup>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group as={Row} className={`mb-3 ${utilStyles.divPadding} ${utilStyles.textCenter}`}>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <Button variant='yellow' onClick={onReset}>Employees&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPeopleGroup} /></Button>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <Button variant='yellow' onClick={onDepartment}>Department Listing&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBuildingUser} /></Button>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <Button variant='grey' onClick={onReset}>Reset&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowsRotate} /></Button>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Group>
      </Container>
    </Form>

  )
}

export default SearchText;




SearchResults

import SearchEmployees from '../search-employees/page';
import SearchDepartments from '../search-departments/page';
    
const SearchResults = ({ setIsLoading, isLoading, selection, searchResults }) => {
  return (

    (selection === 'employees')
    ? <SearchEmployees setIsLoading={setIsLoading} isLoading={isLoading} searchResults={searchResults} />
    : <SearchDepartments setIsLoading={setIsLoading} isLoading={isLoading} />
    
  );
}

export default SearchResults;



SearchEmployees

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import { faPhone, faEnvelope } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';

const SearchEmployees = ({ setIsLoading, isLoading, searchResults }) => {
  var employees;

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 100);
  });

  {(searchResults?.length !== 0) &&
    
   (employees = searchResults.map(employee =>
      <Card className={`col col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-4 ${utilStyles.cards}`} style={{ width: '25rem' }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.ribbon} ${utilStyles.ribbonLight} ${utilStyles.ribbonBottomRight}`}><span>{employee.CAMPUS}</span></Card.Title>
          <Card.Title as="h3" className="card-title card-name">{employee.NAME}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title as="h6" className={`${utilStyles.cardJobtitle} mb-2`}>{employee.JOBTITLE?.length ? employee.JOBTITLE : <br />}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardDepartment}`}>{employee.DEPARTMENT}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardTextBottom}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{employee.PHONE}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardTextBottom}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{parse(employee.EMAIL)}</Card.Title>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
   ))
  };


  return (
    
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        {!isLoading && (employees?.length ? employees : <article><p className={`${utilStyles.cardResults}`}>No Matching Results</p></article>)}
        {isLoading && (<div style={{width: "100px", margin: "auto"}}><Spinner as="span" variant="secondary" aria-hidden="true" animation="border" style={{ width: "4rem", height: "4rem" }}/></div>)}
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default SearchEmployees;



SearchDepartments

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { employees } from '../search-data/data.js';
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import { faPhone, faEnvelope } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';

const SearchDepartments = ({ setIsLoading, isLoading } ) => {
  let departmentListingHeader = '';

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 100);
  });

  employees.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a?.DEPARTMENT < b?.DEPARTMENT ? -1 : (a?.DEPARTMENT > b?.DEPARTMENT ? 1 : 0);
    
  });

  const departments = employees.map((employee) => {
    if (departmentListingHeader !== employee.DEPARTMENT) {
      departmentListingHeader = employee.DEPARTMENT;
      
      
      return (
        <>
        
        <h3 className={`${utilStyles.cardDepartmentListingHeader} ${utilStyles.cardDepartmentListing}`}>{employee.DEPARTMENT}</h3>
        <Card className={`col col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-4 ${utilStyles.cards}`} style={{ width: '25rem' }}>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.ribbon} ${utilStyles.ribbonLight} ${utilStyles.ribbonBottomRight}`}><span>{employee.CAMPUS}</span></Card.Title>
            <Card.Title as="h3" className="card-title card-name">{employee.NAME}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Title as="h6" className={`${utilStyles.cardJobtitle} mb-2`}>{employee.JOBTITLE?.length ? employee.JOBTITLE : <br />}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardDepartment}`}>{employee.DEPARTMENT}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardTextBottom}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{employee.PHONE}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardTextBottom}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{parse(employee.EMAIL)}</Card.Title>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    
        </>
      );
    };

    if (departmentListingHeader === employee.DEPARTMENT) {
      departmentListingHeader = employee.DEPARTMENT;
        
        
      return (
          
        <Card className={`col col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-4 ${utilStyles.cards}`} style={{ width: '25rem' }}>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.ribbon} ${utilStyles.ribbonLight} ${utilStyles.ribbonBottomRight}`}><span>{employee.CAMPUS}</span></Card.Title>
            <Card.Title as="h3" className="card-title card-name">{employee.NAME}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Title as="h6" className={`${utilStyles.cardJobtitle} mb-2`}>{employee.JOBTITLE?.length ? employee.JOBTITLE : <br />}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardDepartment}`}>{employee.DEPARTMENT}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardTextBottom}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{employee.PHONE}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Title className={`${utilStyles.cardText} ${utilStyles.cardTextBottom}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} className={utilStyles.cardTextIcons} /><span className={utilStyles.cardPhoneEmail}>W:</span>{parse(employee.EMAIL)}</Card.Title>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      
        );
    }
  });

  
  return (
    
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        {!isLoading && (departments?.length ? departments : '')}
        {isLoading && (<div style={{width: "100px", margin: "auto"}}><Spinner as="span" variant="secondary" aria-hidden="true" animation="border" style={{ width: "4rem", height: "4rem" }}/></div>)}
      </div>
    </div>

  );
};

export default SearchDepartments;


SearchData

export const employees = 
[
  {
    "ROW_NUMBER": 1,
    "PIDM": 1,
    "NAME": "Presley, Elvis",
    "PHONE": "999",
    "EMAIL": "<a href=mailto:xx@xx.xxx>xx@xx.xxx<\u002fa>",
    "CAMPUS": "Campus 1",
    "DEPARTMENT": "English",
    "JOBTITLE": null,
    "SEARCHTYPE": null,
    "SEARCHHEADER": null
  },
  {
    "ROW_NUMBER": 2,
    "PIDM": 2,
    "NAME": "Dean, James",
    "PHONE": "999",
    "EMAIL": "<a href=mailto:xx@xx.xxx>xx@xx.xxx<\u002fa>",
    "CAMPUS": "Campus 2",
    "DEPARTMENT": "Instructional Resources",
    "JOBTITLE": "Lead Librarian-Systems",
    "SEARCHTYPE": null,
    "SEARCHHEADER": null
  },




Why do you have two almost exactly the same components?

I believe you are talking about SearchEmployees and SearchDepartments.  I did that to keep them separate since Departments is sorted by Department and Employees by name.  Of course, that didn't solve my issue.

In your SearchEmployee, there is no implementation for sorting by name. The data will display the same in order based on data.json.
{
  searchResults?.length !== 0 &&
    (employees = searchResults.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a?.NAME < b?.NAME
        ? -1
        : a?.NAME > b?.NAME
        ? 1
        : 0;
    }).map((employee) => (
      ...
    ));
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

That fixed it.  I guess I thought that setting "setSearchResults(cards);" would reset the order to the order that data.json was in, which, is in Name Order.  That's why I never sorted the Employee results.  DATA.JSON is already in Name Order.  Thank you so much.  Now I have just one more problem to solve.  Probably be making a new question.  I can't figure out how to execute javascript that's in a file.  I have a slider that moves down that shows text.  Works great in HTML but I'm not sure how to handle that in React.
